# Importing CSV splits certain lines

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a fairly simple script that needs to check around 20,000 AD Groups for their membership count.  That all works fine, I can take the list of groups run it through the script and for the most entries it works fine.  However I was getting some errors that I couldn't figure out and hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

I am using the DN of the object to query AD and for around 10% it fails, but when I copy the DN from the file, paste it into a command window and run the command manually it works fine.  Some more checking and it seems that when I read an offending line into my variable there is a line break in the middle for some reason.

When looking at the value of the variable I get the following:

Working Example - "CN=ABC, OU=Location, OU=Distribution Lists, DC=Domain, DC=COM"

Error Example - "CN=ABC, OU=Location, OU=Distribution

Lists, DC=Domain, DC=COM"

It seems to insert a return in-between Distribution and Lists on certain entries in the file.  I have tried deleting the character in-between and replacing it with a space but I get the same result.

Could it be the length?  I am still looking for a common factor but any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Updated with requested content.

```
$Groups = Import-Csv C:\Temp\DLName.csv
write-host ($Groups).Count
$i=1

foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$GroupInfo = Get-ADGroupMembersRecursive -Groups $Group.Name
$MembersCount = ($GroupInfo | Measure-Object).Count
$MembersList = $GroupInfo | Select Name -ExcludeProperty Name
$FriendlyName = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group.Name
    
$Export = $FriendlyName.Name + ", " + $MembersCount 
$Export | Out-File C:\Temp\DLMembers.csv -Append

Write-host $FriendlyName "," $MembersCount

$i
$i++
}
```

Entry 1 and 3 work 2 doesn't, but the formatting here seems to have wrapped the entries.

Name

"CN=Company - DL Name1,OU=Country1 Distribution Lists,OU=Europe,OU=Acc,DC=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=com"
"CN=Company - DL Name2,OU=Country2 Distribution Lists,OU=Europe,OU=Acc,DC=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=com"
"CN=Company - DL Name3,OU=Country3 Distribution Lists,OU=America,OU=Acc,DC=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=com"

Top pic is the failure second pic works.

[image: Not Working]

[image: Working]

List Creation:

```
$SearchScope = "OU=OUName,DC=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=com"
$SearchFilter = {GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'}
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $SearchScope -Filter 
$SearchFilter | Sort-Object Name

foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{

$Group.DistinguishedName | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name
$Group.DistinguishedName | Out-File C:\Temp\DLName.csv -Append

}
```

Comment: Can you show us part of that file, including headers? Please a simple copy/paste when opened in notepad, but of course with sensitive data obscured. Also, please show how you read and created the csv file.

Comment: Please do not try to post this info in comments, because you cannot format it there. Just  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68359510/edit) your question and put the info in there

Comment: just figured that out.  Thanks :)  Main post updated.

Comment: There's possibly a non-printing character like a carriage return / vertical tab / etc in the name - try dumping the string out as bytes and see what the characters encode to - e.g. ```[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Group.Name)```. If you see something like ```13``` or ```10``` in the output they're CR and LF respectively. For example ```aaa`r`nbbb``` gives ```97 97 97 13 10 98 98 98```.

Comment: I see you are creating CSV files manually, without quoting the fields and writing to file with `Out-File`. Because of this, you will get misaligned csv's and I think that's where the trouble starts.  Always use [Export-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), so you can be sure all fields are quoted. BTW, I don't know what your custom function `Get-ADGroupMembersRecursive` does.. Anything like [Get-ADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember) with switch `-Recursive`perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a self-combined comma separated string and Out-File to create CSV files, because that will get you into trouble when fields happen to contain the delimiter character like in this case the comma (which will lead to mis-aligned data).

Your List Creation code should be like this:

```
$SearchBase   = "OU=OUName,DC=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=com"
$SearchFilter = "GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'"
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter $SearchFilter | 
    Sort-Object Name | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\DLName.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Then you can use that csv later to do:

```
$Groups = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\DLName.csv'
Write-Host $Groups.Count

$result = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $GroupInfo = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -Recursive
    # unnecessary.. $MembersCount = ($GroupInfo | Measure-Object).Count
    # unused..      $MembersList = $GroupInfo.Name
    # unnecessary.. $FriendlyName = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group.Name

    # output an object with the wanted properties
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        GroupName   = $Group.Name
        MemberCount = @($GroupInfo).Count  # @() in case there is only one member in the group
    }
} 

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\DLMembers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>As you can see, I'm not using your custom function `Get-ADGroupMembersRecursive` because I have no idea what that outputs.. Also, there is no need for that because you can use the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet with the `-Recursive` switch added</sup>

Comment: Thanks I will give these changes a go and see if they work.  I had issues when running Get-ADGroup -Recursive when groups had multiple levels of nested groups.

The function mentioned came from - https://techwizard.cloud/2020/10/24/get-ad-group-members-recursively/

It seems to work fine for 90% of the groups, and even for the ones that error when I  copy/paste the content in manually.  I will give all the solutions above a go and see where we are after.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @typod Ok, you can use your function `Get-ADGroupMembersRecursive` if you like, but since I don't have that, I can't be sure what it outputs..

Comment: I will swap over to Get-ADGroup -Recursive and see if I get the same results.

Comment: @typod, I think you meant `Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive` there ;). I looked at that function and find it highly inefficient because it keeps calling `Get-ADGroup` and builds the collection with `+=` concatenation which is both time and memory consuming..

Comment: yea I noticed that when running a large batch through the scripts.  Swapped over to Get-ADGroup -Recursive now and will compare the results.

Comment: Hi @Theo just swapped over to your method and as you suggested it's much faster.  I am still getting failures on the same groups as I did before however.  I will see if I can dump the errors out and if there isn't too many do them manually.

Comment: Also while the output to the screen is fine, the CSV output doesn't match.  I get Syetem.Collecetions.Hashtable+KeyCollection, IsReadOnly, ISFixedSize etc

Comment: @typod If that is the result in the CSV file, you're not saving the object(s) properly. `$result` is an array of PsObjects, not a Hashtable. Please run my code **exactly** as written and don't forget the `-NoTypeInformation` switch on Export-Csv.

Comment: Thats sorted the output.  It looks like the editor changed the PSCustomObject to Management.Automation.PSObject.

Still getting failures on the same entries as before, but it's much faster now.  I will look to capture them and output them to another file so I can review.

Comment: Looking at the export from AD I suspect there are some funny characters in the names which are causing this.  Some of the - in the name are showing as ? in the export.  I will  change a few and see if they go through OK.

Comment: Add `-Encoding UTF8` to the Export-Csv lines

Comment: Looks like UTF8 was the key.  Thanks for that